# No option to reply to calendar invitation

Tags: google-calendar, invitation

I received a google calendar invite but there was no option to reply "yes, no, maybe"

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me and others, there is [a thread on the Google Calendar Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/calendar/58scD2duQqE/keu_jqN1CwAJ) where the problem is acknowledged and likely linked to a problem with some calendar invites sent from Outlook.

> This issue has been reported to the team, please use the option to Send Feedback in the meantime to continue to report these issues to Google so they can collect info about your account, and if you are with G-Suite be sure to report it to your Google Account Admin.

As of today there has been no further update on the issue.